# Is there a way to enforce a foreign style upon an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a themes library accompanied by a demo page. The demo page has to use styles from the library (for demonstration) but without utilising the whole elements.

For example, take the following style; (external stylesheet)

```
div.major.minor { /* styling statements */ }
```

It is obvious that a browser will **not** match the first `div` since both classes are required. The latter will be matched, of course.

```
<div class="minor"> &nbsp; </div>
<div class="major minor"> &nbsp; </div>
```

But this is **exactly** what I want to achieve; i.e. the browser should somehow ignore that the style targets `div`'s with both classes, and apply the style to the first one as well.

The following **is not** feasible, since it's not 'logical' to put extra selectors in the library only to use them in the demo page.

```
div.major.minor, div.demo.minor { /* styling statements */ }
```

The solution can even utilise JavaScript, there isn't a requirement to stick to HTML/CSS only. Any workaround will do.

As a last resort, (if no better solution is found) I will replicate the styles I want from the library in an extra stylesheet for the demo page. But of course I want to avoid this, since there's to much repeating code involved.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Add the `major` class to all `.minor` only class elements through javascript

Comment: This is very unclear.  I get that you want to apply the style to both divs, but you could simply remove `.major` from the selector to do that.  Can you give a more "real world" example of something, both outside and within the demo environment?

Comment: I'd probably use LESS or SCSS to do what you are aiming for. You can target the extra selectors with only one line and not cause that duplication that you're worried about.

Comment: You can of course do it with JS, but this is really weird. Create a separate stylesheet. But you probably should not have selectors like `div.major.minor`. `.major.minor` is much better.

Comment: @Archer you're right, I should have provided a more suitable example. To clarify, `major` contains styles unsuitable for the demo (like positioning and floats for `div`s, etc.) whilst `minor` only contains colors. What I'm trying to achieve, is demonstrate only the colors on simple `span` elements. Applying **both** styles would be disastrous.

Comment: I don't understand why you think it is a good idea to have a demo page that demonstrates behaviour that is different to what your theme library would do on its own.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend a demo stylesheet that simply overrides all the positioning etc., and sets it to either inherited or something more relevant for the demo page.  That way you still use the main stylesheet that goes with the theme, but have a static demo override for all themes that styles (or un-styles) the demo pages accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the stylesheet you are working on is going to be a library, you'd better not mess it up just to style your demo page.

These are two separate things and a separate CSS file would ensure that everything goes as planned. Anything else would require more effort than it's really worth and it might make things go downhill.